# How to use onBackPressed in an activity that swipes the screen with another activity?

Tags: java, android

I've a little problem. I've two activities (GalleryActivity and GalleryVideoActivity) and after swiping between them, i would to come back to the first activity (GalleryActivity) pressing just one time on back button because i've to press back button as many times as i swipped. Is it possible? Thanks in advance to everyone!

Comment: Can you please explain more? Your question little bit unclear. Do you want to back to the previous activity by swipe? Did you mean that?

Comment: are you swiping activities with viewpager ?

Comment: @ RezaulIslam yes i'm sorry but it's a little bit difficoult to explain. Suppose we are in the GalleryVideoActivity after swiping the screen 3 times. If I press the button to go back, I will have to press it as many times as I swiped before. I hope now it's more clear to understand

Comment: @takieddine no, i didn't use viewpager

Answer (score 1):

So if i understand your issue is that you are moving between activities and everytime you move they create new instances so as a solution to suggest is as following ,
in your manifest file , in activity section add launchMode="SingleInstance" , as this would create only one instance of that activity .

- This is an example

```
  <activity
            android:name=".ui.apppassword.PasswordRestoreActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
```

Comment: Yes, everytime I move between activities they create new instances. However adding that works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: That's my pleasure to help mate , good luck

Comment: if the answer was helpful please upvote it so someone else finds it helpful too , thank you

Comment: I've already upvoted your answer, thank you very much! ;)

Comment: Oh alright , i guess there is something wrong with site i guess , cause it is not upvated :D , thank you anyway mate good luck

Comment: This is the message when i upvote: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score". Good luck to you too!

Answer (score 0):

In GalleryVideoActivity override onBackpress method and navigate back to the GalleryActivity by putting simple intent.

Comment: I think this solution too, but I dodn't know how to implement onBackPressed. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to add to GalleryVideoActivity in order to implement onBackPressed as Mike stated:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent toGalleryActivity = new Intent(this, GalleryActivity.class);
    startActivity(toGalleryActivity);
}
```

This starts GalleryActivity everytime the back button is pressed in GalleryVideoActivity.

Comment: Yes, I mean something like this but in this way there'll be a loop